# Adding to regex, dont allow certain characters

Tags: regex

I have a regex that does not allow an url to start with `http`, and foreces it to start with `www`. Now I would like to add to it so it does not allow any special characters.

Current regex: `^(?!https?)www\..*$`

Characters I do not want to allow: **!"@#£¤$%&/{([)]=}?+`´*'**

I'm using ASP.NET.

I've tried using negated characters for ex: `[^%!]` to not allow % and !, but can't get it to work, it just checks the first character of the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion at the start which includes the list of characters you want to exclude.

```
^(?!.*?[!"@#£¤$%&\/{(\[)\]=}?+\\`´*'])(?!https?)www\..*$
```

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to answer. However in https://www.regex101.com/ this does not let me write for example "www.test.com"